# When targeting dnx451 I don't seem to be able to add reference to MEF (System.ComponentModel.Composition)

Tags: c#, mef, asp.net-core, dnx

Using the latest beta (beta8) and only targeting dnx451 I thought that I would be able to make use of the full .net client framework.  I am trying to create a plugin infrastructure in a vnext/dnx application where I can reload the plugins without restarting the app using MEF and have seen some examples but it doesn't look like I can use MEF with dnx451 (I am not targeting dnxcore).

Comment: I haven't seen that scenario running yet. If you do, keep us posted!

Comment: One more link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801312/is-there-a-replacement-for-mef-in-net-core-or-asp-net-5

Comment: Reading the other stackoverflow you point to @MaximeRouiller it looks like I should be able to reference MEF without any issues as I am not targeting .Net Core.  I wonder if I have to change from dnx451 to dnx46 or something.

Comment: Mainly the target. You would need to rebuild the NuGet package to include the target platform `dnxcore50` (add `+dnxcore50` at the end of the folder name). nupkg are just zip file so renaming the proper folder and serving the file locally would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just in case anyone else runs across this the main Issue that I ran into was the Visual Studio tooling was not updating the project.json correctly.  Below is an example of how the framework assemblies references should be added (Such as MEF)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "AutoSpark.Runner Class Library",
  "authors": [ "bferr" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
    "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.ComponentModel.Composition": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Reflection.Context": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```