# Is the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) what ASP.NET Core 2 uses internally for IoC?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to gauge if Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) is something I can use for extending an ASP.NET Core 2.x MVC website.  I saw ExtCore also.  My desire is to use it to build infrastructure for plugins in my application.

What I cannot figure out is if MEF is legacy from Silverlight or if MEF is what Core actually uses for it's IoC.  I know MEF is in CoreFX, but that's all I know for sure.

I'd like to use MS's IoC DI here if it is viable and not legacy.  Is MEF legacy or is it used by Core itself?

Some questions I looked at, most were very old,

[Is there a replacement for MEF in .NET Core (or ASP.NET 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801312/is-there-a-replacement-for-mef-in-net-core-or-asp-net-5)

[In ASP.NET Core, does the IoC ASP Startup Class solve what the Managed Extensibility Framework solved with a catalog and container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269797/in-asp-net-core-does-the-ioc-asp-startup-class-solve-what-the-managed-extensibi)
 (The last one is a question I asked at the end of 2016.)